# Reset push switch for LDO regulator

Tags: power, switches, ldo, button

I have a XC6220B331MR-G 3.3 V LDO voltage regulator that supplies power to the MCU along with some other components on my board.

The regulator has an enable pin which I connected to VIN so that the regulator is always on. I wanted to add a push switch which I can press to cut the power momentarily, which will reset the MCU and everything connected to it.

This is what I have right now, and I'm not sure how to incorporate the switch in the design.

[image] the button in the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that with pull-up resistor and push button.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyuOeJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yea that works, I had a follow up question. Why 100k Resistor and not a different value?

Comment: @MostafaIbrahim Actually, it may differ according to the project. When you close the switch, you will draw some current from the battery to the ground. A value between 10k and 100k may be reasonable to limit this current.
Choosing too large values may cause delayed enable when the switch is opened, depending on the amount of capacity on the enable pin.